# Relative discriminant of extension of number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Let $K$ be a number field and let $L$ be an extension of $K$ with respective rings of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$.

I am aware of something called the **relative discriminant** of $L$ over $K$. I'm interested in looking at the ramification properties of a particular $L$.

If I am looking at a number field $K$ and wish to calculate its discriminant over $\Bbb Q$ I can take a $\Bbb Z$-basis for $\Bbb Q$ and calculate the discriminant of those elements (how the absolute discriminant is defined).

If I have an extension $L$ of a number field $K$ and I know an $\mathcal{O}_K$-basis for $L$, can I calculate the relative discriminant in this way, or does this give me something completely different?

Edit: I know that the relative discriminant actually gives an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$, is there an analogous numerical invariant?

Comment: The problem is that $\mathcal{O}_L$ need not be a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module if $K$ doesn't have class number 1. In particular, this is why the relative discriminant is only an ideal: it is generated by the discriminants of all free $\mathcal{O}_K$-submodules of $\mathcal{O}_L$ that are of rank $[L:K] $.

Comment: @BrandonCarter Thanks; is the implication that $\mathcal{O}_L$ definitely **isn't** a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module if $K$ doesn't have class number $1$, or can this still happen? If such an $\mathcal{O}_K$-basis exists, can I just calculate the discriminant of this "relative integral basis" to get a numerical invariant?

Comment: I don't see why $\mathcal{O}_L$ couldn't still be a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module when $K$ doesn't have class number 1, but I don't have an example in mind.

Comment: Even if you do have an $\mathcal{O}_K$-basis, the discriminant of a "relative integral basis" is only defined up $(\det(\mathrm{GL}_{L:K}(\mathcal{O}_K)))^2 = (\mathcal{O}_K^\times)^2$. When $K = \mathbf{Q}$ the discriminant of an integral basis is exactly defined as a numerical invariant. In general, it is defined up to certain units, and so you don't have a natural choice for a numerical invariant. You do get, however, that the relative disc ideal is principal.

Comment: What do you mean by a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @HeinrichWagner idk what I meant hahaha

Answer (score 3):

In general you can't find a basis for $O_L$ over $O_K$ because it isn't always free, but what you can do is this:

Find a basis $b_1, ... , b_n$ for $L$ over $K$ and ideals $I_1, ... , I_n$ of $K$,
such that $O_L = b_1 I_1  + ... + b_n I_n$ (direct sum).

Then the relative discriminant is the product

$\Delta\{b_1,..., b_n\} \cdot (I_1 ... I_n )^2$.

The easiest example is this: let $P$ be a maximal ideal of $K$ whose order in the class group is $2$, so $P^2$ is the principal  ideal generated by an element $\alpha$.
Then you can define $L= K (\alpha^{1/2})$.

In most cases $O_L$ can be written in the form

$1\cdot O_K + \alpha^{1/2}\cdot P^{-1}$.

so the relative discriminant is $(4\alpha)\cdot P^{-2}$.